# Slick - Inserting a row into two tables linked with an auto-incrementing key?

Tags: scala, foreign-keys, auto-increment, slick

I'm new to Slick and struggling to find a good canonical example for the following.

I'd like to insert a row into two tables. The first table has a primary key which auto-increments. The second table is related to the first via its primary key.

So I'd like to:

1. Start a transaction
2. Insert a row into table 1, which generates a key
3. Insert a row into table 2, with a foreign key generated in the previous step
4. End transaction (rollback steps 2 & 3 if either fail)

Would appreciate a canonical example for the above logic, and any related suggestions on my definitions below (I'm very new to Slick!). Thanks!

#### Insert logic for table 1

```scala
private def insertAndReturn(entry: Entry) = 
  entries returning entries.map(_.id) 
  into ((_, newId) => entry.copy(id = newId))

def insert(entry: Entry): Future[Entry] =
  db.run(insertAndReturn(entry) += entry)
```

(similar for table 2)

#### Table 1

```
class EntryTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Entry](tag, "tblEntry") {
  def id = column[EntryId]("entryID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  ... 

  def * = (id, ...).shaped <> (Entry.tupled, Entry.unapply)
}
```

#### Table 2

```
class UsernameChangeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserNameChange](tag, "tblUserNameChange") {
  def entryId = column[EntryId]("entryID")
  ...

  def entry = foreignKey("ENTRY_FK", entryId, entryDao.entries)(
    _.id, onUpdate = Restrict, onDelete = Cascade
  )
```

I'm using a MySQL database and Slick 3.1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All that you have to do is

```
val tx = 
 insertAndReturn(entry).flatMap { id =>
   insertUserNameChange(UserNameChange(id, ...))
 }.transactionally

db.run(tx)
```

Note that `insertUserNameChange` is the function which inserts the `UserNameChange` instance into the database. It needs the EntryId which you get back from the previous insertion action.

Compose actions using `flatMap` and use `transactionally` to run the whole query in a transaction.

Your Slick tables look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a canonical example implementing this functionality

```
package models
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

case class Supplier1(id:Int,name:String)

class Suppliers1(tag:Tag) extends Table[Supplier1](tag,"SUPPLIERS") {
  def id:Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID",O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
  def name:Rep[String] = column[String]("NAME")

  def * = (id,name) <> 
    (Supplier1.tupled,Supplier1.unapply)
}

case class Coffee1(id:Int,name:String,suppId:Int)

class Coffees1(tag:Tag) extends Table[Coffee1](tag,"COFFEES"){
  def id:Rep[Int] = column[Int]("C_ID",O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
  def name:Rep[String] = column[String]("COFFEE_NAME")
  def suppId:Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID")


  def * = (id,name,suppId) <> (Coffee1.tupled,Coffee1.unapply)

  def supplier = foreignKey("supp_fk", suppId, TableQuery[Suppliers])(_.id)
}

object HelloSlick1 extends App{
val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers1]
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees1]
val setUpF = (suppliers.schema ++ coffees.schema).create
val insertSupplier = suppliers returning suppliers.map(_.id)
//val tx =  (insertSupplier += Supplier1(0,"SUPP 1")).flatMap(id=>(coffees += Coffee1(0,"COF",id))).transactionally
val tx = for{
   supId  <- insertSupplier += Supplier1(0,"SUPP 1")

  cId <- coffees += Coffee1(0,"COF",supId)
} yield ()
tx.transactionally

def exec[T](action: DBIO[T]): T =
    Await.result(db.run(action), Duration.Inf)
exec(setUpF) 
exec(tx)       
exec(suppliers.result.map(println))
exec(coffees.result.map(println))
}
```